# Datediff in minutes using Field and literal String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues trying to calculate the difference in Minutes between a Field and a literal string. However the output I am getting doesnt seem right at all, it looks to me like you can't seem to compare a Field and a literal string, however if they both the same then it seems fine i.e both are column values or literal strings.

Here is the SQL

```
select datediff(minute,enquiry,cast('17:00:00' as time))

from [dbo].[Test_Dates]
```

Is there anyway to get the right results, given the enquiry Field has values of hours within business hours. The result from the above query I am getting is as follows: -61536240

Comment: Is your enquiry field datatype DATETIME?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: You should cast enquiry column to time as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should make both fields in time format

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, CONVERT(CHAR(5), enquiry, 108) , CAST('17:00:00' as time))
  FROM [dbo].[Test_Dates]
```

or

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(enquiry as time) , CAST('17:00:00' as time))
  FROM [dbo].[Test_Dates]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select datediff(minute,cast (enquiry as time),cast('17:00:00' as time)) from test_dates as t
```